# Batch encoding MXF to Prores using wildcards on Windows 10

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch, encoding, wildcards

I have created a script to encode an `.mxf` file with two separate audio files into a Prores with two ember ed audio tracks, and it works fine.

However, I would like to be able to batch encode using wildcards for the file names, so how can this be done? Note the files are all `.mxf` and only have a number of digits that are different. The last two digits appear to be different for each of the 3 tracks. Video ends in `40` and audio tracks end in `50` & `60`

```
ffmpeg -i 584198C1V01.5DE998CB.63FF40.mxf ^
       -i 584198C1A01.5DE998CB.63FE60.mxf ^
       -i 584198C1A02.5DE998CB.63FE50.mxf ^
       -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -qscale:v 9 -r 25 ^
       -vf yadif -c:a pcm_s16le -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -map 2:a:0 "Output.mov"
```

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```bat
@echo Off

cd /d "%~dp0" && color 0A
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color 0A & title <nul & title %~nx0

set "_ffmpeg=C:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
set "_stats=-hide_banner -v error -stats"
set "_arg1=c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -qscale:v 9"
set "_arg2=-r 25 -vf yadif -c:a pcm_s16le -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -map 2:a:0"

for %%i in (*40.mxf)do set "_fname=%%~dpnxi" && for /f ^tokens^=* %%x in ('
cmd.exe /v/c "echo= -i "!_fname:~0^,-6!60.mxf" -i "!_fname:~0^,-6!50.mxf!""
')do "!_ffmpeg!" "%%~i" %%x !_arg1! !_arg2! "!_fname:~0,-6!00.mov" !_stats!
```

---

**1.** - Your homework:

- Replace the variables below in a way compatible with your scenario, also go to your bat folder:
- ```bat
  set "_ffmpeg=C:\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" ⇨ set "_ffmpeg=C:\Full\Path\To\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
  ```
- This batch was prepared considering that it will be saved and executed in the folder where you have the files that will be processed, otherwise: edit:
- ```bat
  cd /d "%~dp0" ⇨ cd /d "c:\Folder\Path\To\FilesMXFs"
  ```

**2.** For do this, use one simple `for` list all your files `60.mxf`, for each file output, save the full path in a variable (full/path/name):

```bat
for %%i in (*40.mxf)do set "_fname=%%~dpnxi"
```

**3.** Use one additional `For /F` to `echo=` this full path/name save in `_fmane` variable, but crop the last 6 characters (`:~0,-6`), and add the strings for `60`/`50 respectively`, and also, on forced additional task explained (Obs.: 1 and 2), below:

```bat
                                            ... for /f ^tokens^=* %%x in ('
cmd.exe /v/c "echo= -i "!_fname:~0^,-6!60.mxf" -i "!_fname:~0^,-6!50.mxf!""
')do ...
```

**Obs.: 1** Below the same code without breaking line:

```bat
for /f ^tokens^=* %%x in ('cmd.exe /v/c "echo= -i "!_fname:~0^,-6!60.mxf" -i "!_fname:~0^,-6!50.mxf!""')do ..
```

**Obs.: 2** The `For /f` loop in runtime getting the output by invoking `cmd /v:on /c "command"`

```bat
cmd /v:on ["EnableDelayedExpansion" My Variables] /c [ in "Run Time/This Execution"]
cmd /?

/V:ON   Enable delayed environment variable expansion using ! as the
        delimiter. For example, /V:ON would allow !var! to expand the
        variable var at execution time.  The var syntax expands variables
        at input time, which is quite a different thing when inside of a FOR
        loop. 

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates


[Note 1] cmd.exe /v:on is the same ⇨ cmd.exe /v | cmd.exe /v 

[Note 2] cmd.exe /v:on /c is the same ⇨ cmd.exe /v:on /c | cmd.exe /v /c | cmd /v/c | cmd/v/c

[Note 3] cmd.exe /v:on /c is the same %comspec% ⇨ %comspec% /v:on /c | %comspec%/v:on /c | %comspec%/v/c
```

**4.** To facilitate the composition of ffmpeg's arguments, you can add the keys to the input files already in the order that they will be passed, the 40 together with the variable of the first loop, but the 60 and 50, inside the echo in the second loop:

```bat
for %%i in (*40.mxf)do ......................................................
...................   -i "!_fname:~0^,-6!60.mxf" -i "!_fname:~0^,-6!50.mxf!"
')do "!_ffmpeg!" "%%~i" %%x 

Rem :: Your ffmepg command "!_ffmpeg!" "%%~i" %%x results in the following layout ::

 "!_ffmpeg!" | -i  |      "%%~i"       |                         %%x                     |
_____________|_____|___________________|_________________________________________________|
 "ffmpeg.exe"  -i  "C:\Path\FileF40.mxf" -i "C:\Path\FileF60.mxf" -i "C:\Path\FileF50.mxf"
```

**5.** The arguments/parameters of ffmpeg, are usually long, like yours, so `arg1` and `arg2` were defined in order to compose a single line, so I understand that it is easy to edit it if you prefer to use it in the conventional way:

```bat
set "_arg1=c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -qscale:v 9"
set "_arg2=-r 25 -vf yadif -c:a pcm_s16le -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -map 2:a:0"
...
... "!_ffmpeg!" .... .... !_arg1! !_arg2! .... ...
```

**6.** You also need to define a layout for the name of the target file, just using `output.mov`, it will cause some file to be overwritten at some point, mainly with a loop running through several files, so it is suggested to use same name and `00.mov`, using substring in the same way as the input, and already explained in item **2.**:

```bat
.... --input C:\Path\FileF40.mxf -input...  _arg1.. _arg2 ... --output C:\Path\FileF00.mov
```

**7.** About the _stats variable: `set "_stats=-hide_banner -v error -stats"`

- It's tries to keep the output of the ffmpeg execution in just one line, self-rewriting during the evolution of the execution, where, only when any potential error may appear, it will break the line, facilitating the monitoring of the bath execution, without having the screen quickly full of information, thus being easier and faster, to perceive some error in the execution / code of the script itself...
- ```bat
  set "_stats=-hide_banner -v error -stats"
  .....
  ')do "!_ffmpeg!" "%%~i" %%x !_arg1! !_arg2! "!_fname:~0,-6!00.mov" !_stats!
  ```
- **Obs.: 3** Obviously the horse is tied to the owner's will, as we say in my land, and if you wish/need one conventional layout to the code with no additional suggestions, variable etc…, there is:
- ```bat
  @echo Off
    
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    
  for %%i in (*40.mxf)do ( 
    
     set "_fname=%%~dpnxi"
    
      for /f ^tokens^=* %%x in ('cmd.exe /v/c "echo= -i "!_fname:~0^,-6!60.mxf" -i 
  "!_fname:~0^,-6!50.mxf!""')do (
    
          "C:\FFmpeg\Path-To\Bin\ffmpeg.exe" "%%~i" %%x c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 
  -pix_fmt yuva444p10le -qscale:v 9 -r 25 -vf yadif -c:a pcm_s16le -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 - 
  map 2:a:0 "output.mov" 
        )
    )
    
  %__APPDIR__%Timeout.exe /t -1 & endlocal && goto=:EOF
  ```

- Just one more thing:

  - If you need **`/R`**ecursive at some point:
  - ```bat
    for %%i in (*40.mxf)do ... ⇨ for /r "c:\Folder\Path\To\FilesMXFs" %%i in (*40.mxf)do ...
    ```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[DelayedExpansion (Refer: `cmd /v /c`)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**

  [√] **[Substring in Set command (Refer: `!_fname:~0,-6!`)](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**